# How do I pass column values from multiple tables to the view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm displaying the data from a table called gigs, however it contains a couple of foreign keys to tables 'Bands' and 'Venues' so when using this code in my controller,

```
            string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            var yourgigs = (from g in dbg.gigs
                                   from v in dbg.Venues
                                   from b in dbg.Bands
                                   from ga in g.gigsaccasses
                                   where (ga.Id == user &&
                                   v.venueid == g.venueid &&
                                   b.bandid == g.bandid)
                                   select g);

            return View(yourgigs);
```

it's displaying bandid and venueid in the view which are meaningless integers.  How would I replace those with what I suppose would be b.bandname, v.venuename and also add v.address1 and v.city?  The SQL statement that does this is

```
SELECT        bands.bandname, venues.venuename, venues.address1, venues.city, gigs.whatdate, gigs.starttime
FROM            gigs INNER JOIN
                         bands ON gigs.bandid = bands.bandid INNER JOIN
                         gigsaccass ON gigs.gigid = gigsaccass.gigid INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AspNetUsers ON gigsaccass.Id = dbo.AspNetUsers.Id INNER JOIN
                         venues ON gigs.venueid = venues.venueid
                         WHERE dbo.AspNetUsers.Id = //some user//
```

I did try using anonymous types as such:

```html
 var yourgigs = (from g in dbg.gigs
                            from v in dbg.Venues
                            from b in dbg.Bands
                            from ga in g.gigsaccasses
                            where (ga.Id == user &&
                            v.venueid == g.venueid &&
                            b.bandid == g.bandid
                            select new
                            {
                                bandname = b.bandname,
                                venuename = v.venuename,
                                address1 = v.address1,
                                city = v.city,
                                whatdate = g.whatdate,
                                starttime = g.starttime
                            });
```

But this then threw an error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.TimeSpan]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2.gigs]'.

The View is expecting type 'gigs'

```html
@model IEnumerable<OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2.gigs>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Gigs";
}

<h2>Gigs</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.venueid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bandid)
        </th>
```

What am I missing?

## EDIT:

I should add that I do have a model, but I'm assuming this is what is at fault.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2
{

    [Table("gigs")]
    public partial class gigs
    {
        public gigs()
        {
            this.gigsaccasses = new HashSet<gigsaccass>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int gigid { get; set; }
        public int venueid { get; set; }
        public int bandid { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Date")]
        public System.DateTime whatdate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Starts at")]
        public System.TimeSpan starttime { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<gigsaccass> gigsaccasses { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("gigsaccass")]
    public partial class gigsaccass
    {
        [Key]
        public int gigaccassid { get; set; }
        public int gigid { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public virtual gigs gig { get; set; }
        public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUser { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("dbo.AspNetUsers")]
    public class AspNetUsers
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string YourName { get; set; }

        public List<gigsaccass> gigsaccasses { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("venues")]
    public partial class venues
    {
        [Key]
        public int venueid { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Venue")]
        public string venuename { get; set; }        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string city { get; set; }
        public List<gigs> venuegigs { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("bands")]
    public class bands
    {
        [Key]
        public int bandid { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string bandname { get; set; }
        public List<gigs> bandgigs { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class gigscontext : DbContext
    {
        public gigscontext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<gigs> gigs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<gigsaccass> gigsaccass { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<venues> Venues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<bands> Bands { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove your User's class from the question. That's just inviting someone to hack into your website. It's not necessary to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anonymous classes here. Your view needs to know how to work with model, it needs type information, but: "The type name is generated by the compiler and is not available at the source code level"

You can't pass such objects around. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15624/Inside-C-Anonymous-Methods#5

You need to create class that represent row in your data set and return list of populated objects.

As less preferred alternative you can use `dynamic`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The M in MVC stands for model, and what you want is one of the 3 main tenants of MVC.

You want an object that encapsulates all the information to be displayed on the view.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered best practice to create a model for the view. This is an additional layer which separates the storage of the item (your entity model) from it's presentation.

```
 var yourgigs = (from g in dbg.gigs
                            from v in dbg.Venues
                            from b in dbg.Bands
                            from ga in g.gigsaccasses
                            where (ga.Id == user &&
                            v.venueid == g.venueid &&
                            b.bandid == g.bandid
                            select new GigViewModel
                            {
                                bandname = b.bandname,
                                venuename = v.venuename,
                                address1 = v.address1,
                                city = v.city,
                                whatdate = g.whatdate,
                                starttime = g.starttime
                            });

public class GigViewModel
{
    public string bandname { get; set; }
    public string venuename { get; set; }
    public string address1 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public DateTime whatdate { get; set; }
    public Timespan starttime { get; set; }
}
```

When persisting data from your view models, use AutoMapper or something similar to copy properties with matching names between your view models and your entity models.

Use the new view model in your view:
`@model IEnumerable<OnStageTonight_MVC.Models2.GigModelView>`